# what does it mean when it says find an exact, closed form solution?

Tags: chaos-theory

What does it mean when it says find an exact, closed form solution? I'm currently trying to solve a problem nonlinear difference equation which states that at the end "This is one of the rare cases where a nonlinear difference equation can solved exactly" what does it mean by exactly?

Comment: Exact closed form means an explicit formula for the solution (not an approximation).

Comment: There is a formula for each term in the difference equation in terms of n. e.g $a_{n+1} - a_{n} = 1$ with $a_0 = 1$ is a linear difference equation. In this case $a_1 = 2, a_2 = 3$ and in general $a_n = n+1$. This is a closed form solution for $a_n$ in terms of n - it does not involve any other terms. Being able to do this for none linear difference equations is rare.

Comment: what does it mean to be explicit?

Comment: The solution is *implicitly* defined by the difference equation and initial conditions.  *Explicit* means the solution can be expressed by a formula, just as the Comments here have said.  Why did you tag this with "chaos-theory"?

Comment: I'm working on problems in mathematical modeling, this weeks homework is on Discrete Time Logistic Maps, and Periodic and Chaotic Solutions. Some of the questions are from the Nonlinear Dynamics and Chaos textbook by Strogatz

Comment: Thanks guys! I figured out how to solve the problem